# Java Generics .class

Tags: java, generics

We have an annotation @Accepts:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface Accepts {
  Class[] value();
}
```

It takes a list of Classes. These are later used to validate in a DSL that a field was passed an instance of the classes listed as acceptable.

Some examples of this annotation in use:

```
public enum PropertyName {


  @Accepts({Integer.class})
  xCoordinate,


  @Accepts({Integer.class})
  yCoordinate,

  @Accepts({Boolean.class})
  showPermission

  @Accepts({String.class, FieldScript.class, List.class})
  onClick

  /* And So On*/
}
```

I am adding a new item to this enum called 'value' and it can accept a String or a PropertyResolver. PropertyResolver is an interface defined as below:

```
public interface PropertyResolver<T> {
    public T getValue(TagContext tagContext);
}
```

I don't know how to do a .class on PropertyResolver to pass on to @Accepts. Is it possible to do so?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to do `PropertyResolver.class`. There will only one `Class` instance that represents the the class (raw-version).

No such things as `PropertyResolver<T>.class` or `PropertyResolver<Integer>.class` exist.

Always, keep in mind that in Java, generics is compile time only feature.

Comment: @JakubJirutka Wait, really? When are generics not erased?

Comment: Hmmm, found something that says that dynamic types are erased, but static types are not. Is that what you were referring to?

Comment: @JakubJirutka Ah, that's interesting. Thanks for the info! Learned something new today.